# How to get only the piece of the array closest value after value

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# array, consisting of 1, 2 and 3.3. I only want to display the value closest to, but after X, which in this case is 1.3, which would make this value to display 2. How should I achieve this in an unsorted array?

Comment: you want the closest number that is not lower than x? because 1 is closer than 2 to 1.3

Comment: Asuming it is sorted: a) find the position of the first occurance of X or more. b) Start printing the array from there.

Comment: Have you even tried anything? Please show what you´ve tried, what your input and expected output is and what you get instad.

Comment: `var i = array.indexof(x); var value = array[i + 1];`

Comment: Incrredible that a question that doesn´t show *any* afford gets so heavily upvoted.

Comment: lol, u salty ...

Comment: What should be displayed if X is 1? If X is -4? If X is 3.31?

Comment: when X is 1, it should display 2, when it's -4 it should display 1, and when it's 3.31 it shouldn't display anything

Comment: I added an extra line of code for that, to my knowledge, none of the answers handled 3.31 that way, but that wasn't the biggest issue I was facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by the difference of each item with the desired number and the first one (least difference) will be your number:

```
double answer = theArray.Where(a => a >= x).Min();
```

or

```
double answer = theArray.OrderBy(a => a)
          .SkipWhile(a => a < X).First();
```

Comment: `.OrderBy(a => Math.Abs(a - X)).First()` can be replaced with `Min()`

Comment: @Adrian well its the same thing, if you look all the answers are correct but, everyone thought of a different thing.

Comment: it think it's unneccessary to sort something when its not required

Comment: well that is a example that OP has shown us, it doesn't say its a sorted array.

Comment: You don't have to sort it if you filter with Where then use Min! Thats the whole point

Comment: When i make X the integer it gives me the error that it  can't compare a string to int, and when i make it a string it gives me the error that it can't compare string to string, how can i stop this error from happening?

Comment: oh you said compare a string to int? where is the string?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following LINQ query (assuming the array is sorted):

```
var array = new [] {1, 2, 3.3};
var x = 1.3;
var result =  array.SkipWhile(e => e < x).First();
```

Alternatively, if the array isn't sorted:

```
var result = array.Where(e => e >= x).Min();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++){
    if (num_your_looking_for <= arr[i])
        return arr[i]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get smallest array value which is greater than given value.

```
var value = 1.3;
var closest = array.Where(item => item > value)
                   .Min();
```

Comment: why not just `Min()`?

Answer (score 1):

> ...which in this case is 1.3, which would make this value to display 2

If you only want the next element bigger than 1.3:

```
public static T FirstAfter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, T item) where T : IComparable =>
    collection.First(x => x.CompareTo(item) == 1);

var array = new[] {1, 2, 3.3};
var whatYouWant = array.FirstAfter(1.3);
```